# Maintaining a Laplace distribution under a linear transformation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am working on a paper that involves linear transformations of random variables $X_1, X_2, \cdots, X_k$. The RVs I am dealing with are independently and identically distributed and $X_i \sim \mathrm{Laplace}(0,\nu)$. However, I was wondering if a linear combination of these variables would also follow a Laplace distribution. That is, does $$a_1X_1 + a_2X_2 + \cdots a_kX_k$$
also follow a Laplace distribution? And if it does, is there any change to the mean and the scale parameter? If it does not, why not?

It seems to me that it should maintain its distribution since this is a well-known property of the normal distribution and the Laplace distribution is fairly similar. But I am not able to rigorously prove this or disprove this.

Comment: Try finding the moment generating function or characteristic function of the sum.

Comment: I have got the moment generating function of the sum, but I am not able to understand how to use it to answer my question. The moment generating function, for reference, is $$\frac{1}{2^k} \frac{1}{(1-a_1t)(1-a_2t)\cdots(1-a_kt)}$$

Comment: You need to see if this matches the form of the MGF of a Laplace distribution.